# Concat of several cells with custom separator

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

After applying CONCAT to the range of cells and trying to combine it with custom separators, function returns only the first object of the list.

Function that I'm using - `=CONCAT(A1:A3&" "&ROW()-1&" ")`

It seems that brackets on the sides doesn't let the whole list appear in the cell. I want to apply this function to the whole document, that's why pressing CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER for each CONCAT doesn't seem to be right for me.

The result I am looking for would look like this:

```
ABC 
DBC
ASD
SSD
DFG
DFA
SDF
EGL
ASF
```

After CONCAT

```
ABC 0 DBC 1 ASD 2
SSD 3 DFG 4 DFA 5
SDF 6 EGL 7 ASF 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments on @MátéJuhász his answer you can use [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) to do this (even `CONCAT` will still work with a small adjustment).

So with the sample data you gave you should try:

[image]

In `B1` formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(A:A,1+(ROW()-1)*3):INDEX(A:A,3+(ROW()-1)*3)&" "&ROW(INDEX(A:A,1+(ROW()-1)*3):INDEX(A:A,3+(ROW()-1)*3))-1)
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula and should be entered through <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you want to do this every nth row, simply change all the 3's in the formula to any number, e.g. 16.

And drag the formula down...:)

Comment: NIIIIICE! Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

`CONCATENATE` works only with parameters provided as a list, and it can't handle multiple cells in a range.

Since Excel 2016 you can use [`CONCAT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) function for that (even without TRANSPOSE):

[image]

Unfortunately there is no solution with standard functions for that before Excel 2016.

Comment: Maybe to keep the `,` delimiters you can include the `TEXJOIN` function :)

Comment: @JvdV how to use custom delimiters as a range of numbers on that? From example that would be ABC 0 DBL 1 SSD 2

Comment: If you want it exactly like that, then `CONCAT` will do: `=CONCAT(A1:A3&" "&ROW(A1:A3)-1)` entered as array.

Comment: @ZhangirSiranov, would you want to use `TEXTJOIN` it would be `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:A3&" "&ROW(A1:A3)-1)` as array formula.

Comment: Thank you guys so much @JvdV

Comment: Oopsie. It doesn't seem to work on excel 2019. Any possible limitations there? @JvdV

Comment: @ZhangirSiranov, both options need to be confirmed through a combination of the keys CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Once they are entered as such, you can confirm that by checking the formula has curly brackets at the start and end.

Comment: @ZhangirSiranov: please update your question to reflect all your requirements, then I'll be able to update answer too.

Comment: Just updated it, sorry for not showing all of my requirements at the start. Thought I can figure it out by myself.

Comment: @JvdV, I really appreciate your help, but this unfortunately doesn't seem to work. It says that ROW uses more than 1 parameter - 2 to be exact

Comment: @ZhangirSiranov, woops I changed a `:` in a `,` on accident :S. Try `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(A:A,1+(ROW()-1)*3):INDEX(A:A,3+(ROW()-1)*3)&" "&ROW(INDEX(A:A,1+(ROW()-1)*3):INDEX(A:A,3+(ROW()-1)*3))-1)` instead :)

Comment: @JvdV, WOW! It some kind of excel magic. I might be getting too annoying, but that's the last question. What would I do to expand the length of this TEXTJOIN from 3 to 16? :))

Comment: @ZhangirSiranov I have shut down my pc. Maybe later

Comment: @JvdV, Ok, Thank you for your help! I'll try to figure it out myself from now

Comment: @JvdV: you might submit your own answer and there you could get proper formatting, your contribution would worth its own answer now

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I have posted an answer. I left out the concat, but you can make the same result with concat though. :). Sorry to have made so many comments in your answer.